# How to publish posts in groups without Access Tokens

Tags: facebook

I have the rights to publish a post on the Facebook Group. But I’m not an administrator and I can’t get access_token, can I post a post through the Facebook API somehow?

Answer (score 0):

> But I’m not an administrator and I can’t get access_token

You would need to use a user access token for this anyway; but your app needs to be installed in the group first, and that is a thing only group admins can do.

> can I post a post through the Facebook API somehow?

No, there is no other way.